# Publish geoprocessing service on ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I am following the instructions described [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000007q000000) and I have some enquiries about publishing a GP service.

First of all, how should I publish a GP service on a production environment where the database is clean, without any data. Should I use random input parameters so as to produce a result (which will be empty) , and in turn select Share As > GP Service ?
I cannot use SD file for deploying, So I have to do it using ArcMap

Answer (score 1):

Yes.... the link you mentioned explains that to publish you need to do share as>gp service.

You need to run the tool first to get a result to publish from. So you depending what your tool does, you'll need to provide some sort of input to run it. The schema from the input and output is used to help define the entire service. If you were to run it on desktop just like you'd expect someone to run it when consuming it as a service, you'll be making a better service.